# Create a script to automatically edit a file and runs a command

Tags: command-line, scripts, fan, temperature

I've searched the forums but being a newbie can't find something that I can understand.

I am trying to create a script that edits 3 specific lines on the text, saves it and runs the restart command for the service. This is being done for fan control. I haven't found a GUI yet so I manually edit the speeds since it's summer and during the day I need higher fan speeds.

Before somebody says make it temperature based, I want the temp to stay below a certain degree and during the night lower fan speed is ok so its kind of impossible.

```
sudo nano /etc/fancontrol
sudo service fancontrol restart
```

commands that I run daily but I got bored of editing them all the time. Let's say I could use 2 scripts( one with higher and one with lower fan speeds) and run them manually or automatically at a specific hour.

```
# Configuration file generated by pwmconfig, changes will be lost
INTERVAL=10                                                                                                                                                             
DEVPATH=hwmon1=devices/platform/coretemp.0 hwmon2=devices/platform/it87.2608                                                                                            
DEVNAME=hwmon1=coretemp hwmon2=it8728                                                                                                                                   
FCTEMPS=hwmon2/pwm2=hwmon2/temp2_input hwmon2/pwm3=hwmon1/temp4_input                                                                                                   
FCFANS=hwmon2/pwm2=hwmon2/fan2_input hwmon2/pwm3=hwmon2/fan1_input                                                                                                      
MINTEMP=hwmon2/pwm2=10 hwmon2/pwm3=25                                                                                                                                   
MAXTEMP=hwmon2/pwm2=80 hwmon2/pwm3=55                                                                                                                                   
MINSTART=hwmon2/pwm2=**220** hwmon2/pwm3=210                                                                                                                                
MINSTOP=hwmon2/pwm2=**200** hwmon2/pwm3=200                                                                                                                                 
MAXPWM=hwmon2/pwm2=**220** hwmon2/pwm3=255
```

Bold values are the one I need to change.

Thank you in advance guys!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `sed` command to edit a file using a command. For example,

```
sed -i 's/MINSTART=hwmon2\/pwm2=220/MINSTART=hwmon2\/pwm2=400/' /etc/fancontrol
```

will change the value `220` to `400`.

`s` means "search". After the delimiter `/` that separates the command in parts, the string to search follows, until the next (not escaped) `/`. The `\/` is an escaped `/`, meaning: "interpret next `/` as a literal character belonging to the search string instead of as a delimiter for the different parts of the command. Then follows the string you replace with, terminated with `/`. After the terminating `/`, you can add options. An important one is `g`, which means that any occurrence should be replaced. By default, only the first occurrence found is replaced.

Making the search string specific decreases the chance that it also matches something else in the file.

Comment: Deleted last comment. Thank you for your response. Managed to make it work. three line of your code above and lastly restart service. now at last I don't need to manually edit every time lol.

Comment: add your scripts to cron maybe so you can schedule them to run when you want unattended.